# XNA C# .txt file Tile Engine

Tags: c#, xna

I'm not very experienced when it comes to using .txt files in XNA and therefore i need some help.

I'm tring to make a Tile Engine read and put information depending on what number is in the .txt document. It looks something like this:

```
1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 etc
```

Now, this document contains 50 characters in X (25 without [ , ]) and has 15 lines in Y. The problem is that it only reads the first line in Y and not the other 14 remaining ones in Y, which is causing it to crash.

Here is the code:

```
public void LoadMap(string MapName)
    {

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("Content/" + MapName + ".txt"))
        {

            do
            {
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                string[] numbers = line.Split(',');

                int temp = 0;

                    for (int y = 0; y < loopY; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < loopX; x++)
                        {

                            Blocks[y, x] = new Block();

                            //Crashes here when temp reaches 25
                            if (int.Parse(numbers[temp]) == 1)
                                Blocks[y, x].color = Color.Blue;

                            else if (int.Parse(numbers[temp]) == 2)
                                Blocks[y, x].color = Color.Violet;

                            else
                                Blocks[y, x].color = Color.White;

                            temp++;
                        }

                    }

            } while (!streamReader.EndOfStream);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Where are loopY and loopX defined?

Comment: Are you sure that loopX is staying within bounds of `numbers[]`? What's the exception you're seeing?

Comment: They are defined just above the code that i posted, they look like this: int loopX = GameScreen.Screen.X / 32; int loopY = GameScreen.Screen.Y / 32;     Screen.X is 800 : Screen.Y is 500 and i divided them by 32 to get how many blocks it would need to cover the screen.

Comment: "Index was outside the bounds of the array." Yes i checked it loopX is 25 and Numbers is 25.

Comment: 1. It is unsafe to access numbers[temp], since temp might potentially be larger than array length. 2. You are overwriting Blocks[y,x] for each line.

Comment: @Iskalder `numbers[]` is zero-indexed, so the upper bounds is `numbers[24]`. If `loopX` is 25 then, yes, you'll see an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your reply to my question:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array." Yes i checked it loopX is 25 and Numbers is 25

`numbers[]` is zero-indexed, so the upper bounds is `numbers[24]`. If `loopX` is 25 then, yes, you'll see an exception.

You're iterating through loopX and then loopY and incrementing `temp` every time. You'll either need to set `temp` back to `0` after each loopX iteration, or just use the `numbers` array instead of the loop values instead.

I suggest changing your loop to use `numbers` instead:

```
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.Length; x++)
```

And then, to use your existing code, check value using:

```
if (int.Parse(numbers[x]) == 1)
```

EDIT: This is what I was trying to explain:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("Content/" + MapName + ".txt"))
{
    int y = 0;

    do
    {
        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

        string[] numbers = line.Split(',');

        for (int x = 0; x < numbers.Length; x++)
        {
            Blocks[y, x] = new Block();

            if (int.Parse(numbers[x]) == 1)
                Blocks[y, x].color = Color.Blue;

            else if (int.Parse(numbers[x]) == 2)
                Blocks[y, x].color = Color.Violet;

            else
                Blocks[y, x].color = Color.White;
         }

           y++;

        } while (!streamReader.EndOfStream);


    }
```

Comment: I actually got it to NOT crash by doing this: if (temp == 25) { temp = 0; } But my problem still remains and that is, that it only reads the first line in the .txt document and not the other 14 lines in Y.

Comment: Each time you iterate the `Do` loop, you're reading a single line. You could use the `temp` variable to address that. I'll edit my answer again in just a moment.

Comment: @Iskalder I threw in my edit. It's not tested and could be buggy due to typos, but I figure it gets the point across.

Comment: Hi! Yeah now im seeing what you mean, and it actually works quite fine! I didn't think about using "numbers" in the for loop, quite smart ;) Thanks btw!

Answer (score 2):

I see following things in your code, which seem suspicious to say the least:

1. If your temp >= numbers.Length, than you will get "Index was outside the bounds of the array".
2. If that happens after reading the first line, of course you will not read any further lines, because you got an exception and it will break.
3. You are overwriting your Blocks with every new line: If you read the first line and get into x and y loops, at the very first iteration of x and y, they will both be 0. So you write `Blocks[0,0] = new Block()`. After you read the next line, you get again into x and y loops. They start again with 0, so at the very first iteration of x and y while processing the second line you will write `Blocks[0,0] = new Block()`. Which will in fact overwrite the Block you wrote previously on index [0,0] during the handling of the first line. The same problem exists for all other combinations of x and y.

Debug, step-through and watch variables. That will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply, what you explain seems very logical however i did debug and each time it reaches loopY it resets X but Y stays the same. So it goes like this Blocks[0,0] - loop through X until 25 then it loops through Y Blocks[1,0] Blocks[2,0] etc

Comment: And what happens with Blocks[0,0] when you are handling the next line? Make sure you understand, what the difference between yours and Bill's code is. Otherwise you did not achieve much, apart form getting this tiny peace of code working :)

Comment: Yeah it reseted Y when it was done looping Y. Which is true that it does actually reset Blocks. Sorry didn't see it until i did debug through all the loops in Y which took a while.